# Text on touch in Algodoo

Tags: game-design, scripting

I have just started off in Algodoo and have only a basic knowledge of how it works.

I want to be able to create something that when it is touched by a ball with an English flag on, it shows England and when it is touched by a ball with an American flag, it says America.

How would I do this?

Comment: Presumably you started by checking out documentation on [how to make something happen when a collision is detected](https://algodoo.fandom.com/wiki/Your_Guide_To_OnCollide) and [setting text on an object](https://www.reddit.com/r/Algodoo/comments/8z79th/setting_an_objects_text_to_a_variable/), yes? What did you try so far based on this research?

Comment: @DMGregory i have indeed read these documentations and the most i have got from them got me as far as (e)=>{e.other.text := "Hello World!"}

Comment: ^^ that worked acrually i didnt have my text size large emough to be able to see it. Thanks

Comment: Want to write up your solution as an Answer?

Comment: Howd i do that?

Comment: At the bottom of this page, you should see a text entry box labeled "Your Answer" or, if you're using the StackExchange app, a blue button that says "Add an answer" — use that. Putting "solved" in the title isn't actually recognized as a solution by our Q&A system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K so i fixed it. I didnt have the text size large enough for it to be seen so yea. Beginners mistake

Comment: Please don't forget to mark this as "accepted" in a couple of days!

Comment: This answer would be better if it showed the code you used to set the text, and the steps you needed to take to make the text large enough to be seen.